# ¿Cómo reemplazar elementos de un Array por los de otro bajo determinada condición en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos arreglos:

```
const myArray1 = [{updatedProp: 'prop'}, {updatedProp2: 'prop2'}];
const myArray2 = [{oldProp: 'oldProp'}, 'Una cadena', {oldProp2: 'oldProp2'}];
```

¿Cómo hago para que bajo la condición de que si el elemento es un `Object`, deba reemplazarse por el nuevo en el orden que se encuentran inicialmente los arrays?

El resultado que espero es:

> [updatedProp, 'Una cadena', updatedProp2]

Es decir, algo como:

```
const myUpdateArray = myArray2.map(element => {
  if(typeof element === 'object'){
    return //elemento actualizado
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const myArray1 = [{updatedProp: 'prop'}, {updatedProp2: 'prop2'}];
const myArray2 = [{oldProp: 'oldProp'}, 'Una cadena', {oldProp2: 'oldProp2'}];

let contador = 0;

let resultado = myArray2.map(e => {
 // si es objeto retorna un elemento de myArray1 en la posicion
 // contador
 if(typeof e === 'object') return myArray1[contador++];
 // si no es objeto retorna la cadena
 return e;
 
});

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Por favor edita tu respuesta y agrega una explicación razonable. Saludos

Comment: Los comentarios están en el código.

Comment: Me ganaste jeje

Comment: Gracias, bastante simple. Te marcaré como respuesta. Subiré mi intento de hacerlo haciendo reverse() en el arreglo de objetos actualizados más pop() en la condición.

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver esto simplemente crea un index que empiece por 0, mapea el array antiguo y si la propiedad es un objeto (`typeof p === 'object'`) retorna la propiedad del array de actualización en la posición del index actual y luego incremente el index, si no es un objeto (el item actual del array antiguo) no se incrementará el valor de index por lo que la posición será reservada para cuando sea un objeto nuevamente, todo esto es tomando en cuenta que pides un reemplazo en el orden que se encuentran inicialmente los arrays.

**Mira el ejemplo**:

```js
const myArray1 = [{updatedProp: 'prop'}, {updatedProp2: 'prop2'}];
const myArray2 = [{oldProp: 'oldProp'}, 'Una cadena', {oldProp2: 'oldProp2'}];

replace(myArray1, myArray2, res => {
  console.log(res)
  document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)
})

function replace(update, old, cb) {
  let iR = 0;
  var newArr = old.map(p => {
    iR = typeof p === 'object' ? iR +1 : iR;
    return typeof p === 'object' ? update[iR-1] : p;
  })
  return cb(newArr)
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Espero que sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Puse el arreglo con los elementos actualizados al revés y reemplace los elementos viejos por los actualizados en la posición del objeto cada vez que la condición lo requería sacándolos en orden con pop().

```js
const myArray1 = [{updatedProp: 'prop'}, {updatedProp2: 'prop2'}].reverse();
const myArray2 = [{oldProp: 'oldProp'}, 'Una cadena', {oldProp2: 'oldProp2'}];

const myUpdateArray = myArray2.map(element => {
  return typeof element === 'object' ? myArray1.pop() : element;
});

console.log(myUpdateArray);
```